# PowerPivot - How to Filter Dimension to Get Value

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I am working on a PowerPivot report that has the following tables/relationships:

FactTable:

- SponsorId
- OfficeId
- Type
- Color
- Quantity

DimSponsor:

- SponsorId
- SponsorName
- ProjectName

DimOffice:

- OfficeId
- Region
- Country
- Manager
- NumberEmployees

Relationships exist FactTable to each of the two dimension tables.

I wish to create a calculated measure that is the SUM(Quantity)/SUM(NumberEmployees) which represents the average number of items processed by number of employees.

I believe I am having the problem listed [here at PowerPivotPro FAQ](http://powerpivotfaq.com/Lists/TGPPF/DispForm.aspx?ID=107)

When I create a pivot table that has an X-Axis of [Region] with [NumberEmployees] as the only value it always displays the sum of ALL [NumberEmployees] regardless of any slicer selection (in this case, I created a horizontal slicer of [SponsorName]).

I am new to DAX and have struggled to find a formula to meet my needs.  Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found working examples of what I needed to accomplish on [Marc Russo's blob](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/marco_russo/archive/2009/12/07/many-to-many-relationships-in-powerpivot.aspx).  It is a matter of creating a custom measure that filters the Office table by the already filtered rows of FactTable.

As some of the comments on the page mention, it isn't as easy as drag-n-drop but it works.